# Count how many times a file was downloaded in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am building a website and I have a button which allows an user to download a file.

Here is how my table in phpmyadmin looks like:

[image]

And here is my code that allows an user to download a file:

```
<a href="data/<?php echo $date['name']; ?>" download><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Prenesi"></a>
```

How can I store a number of times the button was clicked in my MySQL table? I only found a topic where somebody wanted to store a number of downloads in TXT file, but I don't want to do that.

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: `update TABLE set downloaded = downloaded + 1 where id = VALUE`

Comment: Yes, but I need to know how to run this code when the button is pressed..

Comment: Use js/jquery to track the clicks and update the db via ajax.

Comment: Don't send the request direct to the file, count it first, then send them the file.

Comment: Okay, I will try with that.

Comment: serverside: use a GET array with `href`.

Comment: where is your code? its hard to explain if you dont have a sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For to catch request you can use GET or POST form methods. Simple example:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <a href="data/<?php echo $date['name']; ?>" download>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Prenesi">
    </a>
</form>

<?php
    if($_POST["submit"]) {
        // database connection and update code
        // update TABLE set downloaded = downloaded + 1 where id = VALUE
        echo 'Updated download count';
    }
?>
```